# If Cell is blank add SUM of another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If a cell in `TT[Fiscal Law 301 CBT]` is blank i would like to add the numbers in `TT[Helper1]`

`CountBlank` doesnt work because I need to sum of column `TT[Helper]`. Other issues i've tried is counting the number of `""` but it always brings back zero.

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following formula

```
=IF(TT[Fiscal Law 301 CBT]="", TT[Helper1],TT[Fiscal Law 301 CBT])
```

you would need to generate another table filled with this formula that would check fiscal law for a blank value.  when there is a blank it pulls from helper1, and when there is no blank it pulls the value from fiscal law.  Normally I would be referencing individual cell address like D2, so there may be an issue with the table referencing method which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Thank you, you were right i had to adjust the formula to: `=IF($G2="",$AA2,"")`. Only downside is i have multiple columns that need that. so i will have a few helper columns to calculate correctly but no biggy!